# Combining field data from multiple shapefiles into one queryable layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, union, append

How do you combine multiple field collected data set in shapefile form in to a single layer in ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

Comment: Please edit this question to more completely describe your goal.  A diagram liking features and attributes, and a description of those attributes would not be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the merge tool. If the fields from the individual layers to be combined are not named the same, but contain the same information, you can use field mapping within the merge tool.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm